# Scrollbar per tab in Notebook not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am exploring python right now and i am making a GUI with a Notebook and tabs are made on click at the options menu. My problem is that the scrollbar won't work on every tab. Could anyone help me with this? Here is my code as of now.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

class Frame:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title("Test")
        self.root.resizable(False, False)
        self.notebook = Notebook(self.root)
        self.notebook.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=2, pady=2)
        self.first_tab = Text(height=22, width=50)
        self.notebook.add(self.first_tab, text= "tab1")

        self.scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.root, command=self.first_tab.yview())
        self.first_tab.config(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
        self.scrollbar.grid(row=1, column=10, sticky="NSW")

        self.mb = Menu(self.root)
        self.root.config(menu=self.mb)
        self.sub_mb = Menu(self.mb, tearoff=0)

        self.mb.add_cascade(label='Options', menu=self.sub_mb)
        self.sub_mb.add_command(label='Create new tab', command=self.create_new_tab)

    def create_new_tab(self):
        self.new_tab = Text(height=22, width=50)
        self.new_tab.config(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
        self.notebook.add(self.new_tab, text="New Tab")

    def launch(self):
        self.root.mainloop()



f = Frame()
f.launch()
```

Comment: Use self.notebook.add(tk.scrolledtext.ScrolledText(height=10, ...), text='tab1') instead.